# Adding a text watermark

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-8, cfpdf, cfimage

I've learned how to add a watermark to a pdf.

```
<cfpdf action="addwatermark" image="NoteToSelf.png" 
    pages="1" 
    position="0,0" 
    showOnPrint="no"
    source="my.pdf" 
    destination="#myDir#\new.pdf" 
    overwrite="yes"
    opacity="10">
```

The way I read it, the watermark has to be an image.  But NoteToSelf.png needs to be text that I've read from a database.

Q: How can I add text as a watermark?

Q: If I am required to use an image for the watermark, then how do I use the ImageNew tag to create an image of text?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ColdFusion 8.0.1 onwards you can supply text directly to the cfpdf tag:

```
<cfpdf action="addwatermark" position="10,10" text="I am the watermakr" source="pdfContent" rotation="90" foreground="yes">
```

If you are not on on 8.0.1 then you would need to use imageNew and the image write text functions and pass that in.

Comment: Thanks Sam!  It's amazing what you can do with 1 line of code in ColdFusion!

Comment: Thx Sam- this is NOT in the current docs, and "text" is NOT an attribute of cfpdf in current online docs. But finding this saved my bacon.